# EmberJS - check if template exists

Tags: ember.js

How can I check if a template exists in an Ember Route object?

I need to check this inside a route; if it does not exist, I will render a default template for that route.

Many thanks!

Comment: Every route has one template corresponding to that route, if you want  you can point that to other template by modifying the `templateName` property of the Route. I dont get what you are about to check?

Comment: I have a base form route that is inherited by all other routes that contain a form (to be submitted). By default, the base route renders a default template (let's say default.hbs). For a specific route (say /foo) that extends Base, it will render default.hbs; if I define foo.hbs, I want the route to be rendered using foo.hbs, not default.hbs. This can be achieved by manually specifiyng foo.hbs, but I want to do it automatically, based on the file name and path, if it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the template you can use `Ember.getOwner(this).lookup("template:foo")` where `foo` is the name of the template. If it returns null, then the template doesn't exist:

```
if (Ember.getOwner(this).lookup("template:foo")) {
  // render template foo
} else {
  // render default template
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating template run time then check template as following:

```
if (Ember.TEMPLATES["index"] == null) {
  Ember.TEMPLATES["index"] = Ember.Handlebars.compile(content);
}
this.render('index', {
  into: 'application'
});
```

Comment: I am not creating it at runtime; the .hbs file exists apriori. I can load it manualy by specifying templateName in the route, but I want it to be loaded automatically, based on the route's URI.